# returning displayobject from proxy class in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, proxy

I have made a proxy class that wraps a displayobject.

Is it possible to call addChild(proxyObject) in anyway rather than addChild(proxyObject.wrapped) ?

I have thought about extending from the proxy object but I think that this is for adding dynamic properties and iterating them.  Alternatively perhaps I could extend from object and use valueOf() or something like that?

thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 2):

If your proxy class extends DisplayObjectContainer (or any class extending it) you can add it directly to the display list.

Comment: are you certain there is no form of operator overloading like the dot operator that will allow me to achieve this?  I can't extend the displayobject or subclasses of etc. as I am hooking into the inheritance chain.

Comment: You can't add to the display list an object which isn't a `DisplayObject` (and if it has to contain children it has to be a `DisplayObjectContainer`)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bad idea to extend valueOf().  Please don't do it.  If you can't extend the DisplayObject, use proxyObject.wrapped.